# I am getting an error saying 'BrowserRouter' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the following code which is giving an error
Is is that I am importing BrowserRouter incorrectly or something?
Can someone please help me figure this out?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: In your snippet you are not importing `BrowserRouter`. Import it from `react-router-dom`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are not currently importing `BrowserRouter` at all.
You will need to add this line to your import statements.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
```

You'll also need to install the `react-router-dom` dependency if you haven't done that.